# Regular expression for detecting and deleting duplicated paragraphs

Tags: php, regex

I'm running a people's platform where humans improve/validate transcriptions of one minute audio records.

Some users copy & paste the transcription one or more times into the text area and then sends to us. It's a kind of spam.

I'm working in a regex that allows me to detect and delete the duplicated text. Here is what I have for now:

The regex works in 2/4 cases.

This is:

```
preg_replace("#(^.*$)((?:.+^\1$)+)#ms", "$1", $Transcription)
```

This are the cases:

**Case 1: the original transcription plus only 1 repetition**

```
//Transcription with only 1 repetition
$Transcription = "[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-";
```

The function works OK:

```
$Transcription = preg_replace("#(^.*$)((?:.+^\1$)+)#ms", "$1", $Transcription);
```

The result:

```
print $Transcription;
```

See it here:
https://regex101.com/r/yibyuT/5

**Case 2: The original transcription plus 2 repetitions**

```
//Transcription with 2 repetitions
$Transcription = "[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-...",
```

The function applied:

```
$Transcription = preg_replace("#(^.*$)((?:.+^\1$)+)#ms", "$1", $Transcription);
```

The result it's OK:

```
print $Transcription;
```

See it here:
https://regex101.com/r/yibyuT/6

**Case 3: The original transcription plus 3 repetitions**

```
//Transcription plus 3 repetitions
$Transcription = "[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-",
```

The function applied:

```
$Transcription = preg_replace("#(^.*$)((?:.+^\1$)+)#ms", "$1", $Transcription);
```

The result shows the original transcription plus 1 repetition, so it's not OK:

```
print $Transcription;
```

**Case 4 The original transcription plus N iterations and some text between each and/or at the beginning and/or at the end**

```
//Original transcription with 1 repetition and some text here and there
$Transcription = "some text here."./*Here start the original prhase*/."[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-"./*Here ends the original phrase*/."."./*Yes, a dot. Only a dot as 'some text between the repetitions'*/.""./*Here start the first repetition. Please note the vertical white space at the beginning*/.
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-/*Here ends the first repetition.*/
fddjkdfjk djk fdjkf djk fdjk fjkdfj kdjfkdj fjdkf jdjf d


/*some text at the end. Please note the several vertical white space at the end*/";
```

The function applied:

```
$Transcription = preg_replace("#(^.*$)((?:.+^\1$)+)#ms", "$1", $Transcription);
```

The result shows the original transcription plus some not-repated text here and there,so it's not OK too:

```
print $Transcription;
```

I need only one function for all cases (only one repetition or two or more repetitions) including the possibility of non-repeated words or phrases into $Transcription which will not be detected nor deleted.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

I think this was an interesting question, had me pondering for a bit, but I think I found your solution.

---

### Code

**Regex**

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yibyuT/2)

```
(^.*$)((?:\v+^\1$)+)
```

**Note:** For languages that don't use PCRE regex, you'll have to replace `\v` in the above regex to `[\r\n]`

**Replacement** (nothing)

---

### Results

#### Input

```
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
```

#### Output

```
[00:00:02] Hola, buenos días.
[00:00:03] Hola buenos días ¿Leo?
[00:00:07] Sí, sí, yo soy.
[00:00:07] Encantada de... De saludarle Leo. Mi nombre es y le llamo de. El motivo de mi llamada, Leo, es porque tenemos a nuestro técnicos especialistas en seguridad en su zona, ya que estamos actualizando la seguridad, porque hemos recibido pues varias solicitudes y llamadas de información por parte de vecinos, y simplemente era saber cuándo tendría diez minutitos para poder recibir usted la información ¿Cuándo le vendría mejor, Leo, está tarde o mañana?
[00:00:34] Er... Er... Por la tarde si quiere.
[00:00:37] Por la tarde, vale ¿Y cuál es el mejor horario...? ¿Las cinco, las seis?
[00:00:43] No, espera, es una tienda.
[00:00:46] Es una tienda, vale, entonces, un poquito por ser... ¿Cuánto me-. ¿Cuándo tiene menos trabajo normalmente a primera hora a las cinco, a las siete y media o a las ocho...?
[00:00:53] [SUPERPUESTO 00:00:53].
[00:00:53] A las cinco... A las cinco.
[00:00:56] ¿A las cinco? Vale, pues dime la dirección de la tienda Leo.
[00:01:00] Er... ¿Qué co-...? ¿Qué nombre es la compañía?
[00:01:03] Er... Somos Secu-
```

---

### Explanation

- `(^.*$)` Capture the following into the first capture group

  - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
  - `.*` Match any character any number of times (with `s` modifier, this also catches new lines)
  - `$` Assert position at the end of the line
- `((?:\v+^\1$)+)` Capture the following into the second capture group

  - `(?: ... )+` Match the following one or more times

    - `\v+` Match one or more vertical whitespaces (including vertical tabs, newlines, etc.) - For non-PCRE regex flavours, use `[\r\n]` instead
    - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
    - `\1` Backreference to capture group 1
    - `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution. I'm forget to add htmlentities transformation. The question is already updated. Please check

Comment: Why don't you reverse the two lines of code so the regex runs before the `htmlentities()`? This changes the question and code required to parse it since it's no longer multiline

Comment: Additionally original answer doesn't resolve the possibility of non-repeated words or phrases into $Transcription which not will be detected nor deleted.

Comment: @EstebanGorupicz clarification is needed for your previous comment, are you trying to remove duplicate words? If so this would require a different regex. The original regex posted here works for the original input/output. It only works because of the multiline nature of the original input

Comment: Forget the htmlentities transformation. I'll remove from there. Original answer doesn't resolve the possibility of non-repeated words or phrases into $Transcription which not will be detected nor deleted

Comment: in fact only works with the second example. Nor the first nor the third

Comment: I replaced \v+ with .+ to include when is not a vertical white space between repetitions. More cases added. Thanks for all

Comment: You should replace `\v+` with `[\r\n]+` instead as `\v` catches vertical whitespace and `.` catches any character except newline unless the `s` flag is used.